# Solve diophantine equation $x^4+4y^4=n$

Tags: diophantine-equations, prime-factorization

Is there a way to solve diophantine equation of form $x^4+4y^4=n$ where $x,y$ are integers, and $n$ is large RSA modulus of size about 1024 bits?

$x^4+4y^4=n$ - it's Sophie Germain identity, which can be factored into

$$(x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2)(x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2) = ((x+y)^2+y^2)((x-y)^2+y^2).$$

Does that equation allow to factorize $n$ (better than brute-force n^1/4) or decrypt given ciphertext?

[It was last year ctf task(2017 asis, Sofies Verden), but there is no solution available for it]

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @kasia Tutej have a look o equation$x^4+5y^4=z^4$ and comments on this site, it will give you good idea.